# Retrofit Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

I'm fairly new to JSON parsing, I'm using the Retrofit library of Square and ran into this problem.

I'm trying to parse this JSON reponse:

```
[
      {
        "id": 3,
        "username": "jezer",
        "regid": "oiqwueoiwqueoiwqueoiwq",
        "url": "http:\/\/192.168.63.175:3000\/users\/3.json"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "username": "emulator",
        "regid": "qwoiuewqoiueoiwqueoq",
        "url": "http:\/\/192.168.63.175:3000\/users\/4.json"
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "username": "test",
        "regid": "ksadqowueqiaksj",
        "url": "http:\/\/192.168.63.175:3000\/users\/7.json"
      }
]
```

Here are my models:

```
public class Contacts {

    public List<User> contacts;

}
```

...

```
public class User {

    String username;
    String regid;

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return(username);
    }  

}
```

my Interface:

```
public interface ContactsInterface {

    @GET("/users.json")
    void contacts(Callback<Contacts> cb);

}
```

my success method:

```
@Override
public void success(Contacts c, Response r) {
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < c.contacts.size(); i++) {
        String name = c.contacts.get(i).toString();
        Log.d("Names", "" + name);
        names.add(name);
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, names);
    mSentTo.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
}
```

When I use it on my success method it throws the error

> Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column2

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 187, accepted):

Right now you are parsing the response as if it was formatted like this:

```
{
  "contacts": [
    { .. }
  ]
}
```

The exception tells you this in that you are expecting an object at the root but the real data is actually an array. This means you need to change the type to be an array.

The easiest way is to just use a list as the direct type in the callback:

```
@GET("/users.json")
void contacts(Callback<List<User>> cb);
```

Comment: @AzlanJamal the same way

Answer (score 23):

**`dependencies used :`**

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
```

json responses can be an `array response` or an `object response` or even a combination of both. See the following three cases

**`Case 1 : Parsing a json array response`** (OP's case)

This case applies to those `json responses` which are of the form **`[{...} ,{...}]`**

E.g.

```
[
  {
    "id": 3,
    "username": "jezer",
    "regid": "oiqwueoiwqueoiwqueoiwq",
    "url": "http:\/\/192.168.63.175:3000\/users\/3.json"
  },
  .
  .
]
```

First create a model class for this array or just goto [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) and auto generate one like below

**`Contacts.java`**

```
public class Contacts {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("username")
@Expose
private String username;
@SerializedName("regid")
@Expose
private String regid;
@SerializedName("url")
@Expose
private String url;

public Integer getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getUsername() {
return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
this.username = username;
}

public String getRegid() {
return regid;
}

public void setRegid(String regid) {
this.regid = regid;
}

public String getUrl() {
return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
this.url = url;
}

}
```

**`ContactsInterface`**

In this case you should return a list of objects like the following

```
public interface ContactsInterface {
@GET("/users.json")
Call<List<Contacts>> getContacts();
}
```

Then make the `retrofit2` call like the following

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("baseurl_here")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    ContactsInterface request = retrofit.create(ContactsInterface.class);
    Call<List<Contacts>> call = request.getContacts();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Contacts>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Contacts>> call, Response<List<Contacts>> response) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response.body().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Contacts>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Error",t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

`response.body()` will give you the list of objects

YOU MAY ALSO CHECK THE FOLLOWING TWO CASES FOR REFERENCE

**`Case 2 : Parsing a json object response`**

This case applies to those json responses which are of the form {..}

E.g.

```
{
"id": 3,
"username": "jezer",
"regid": "oiqwueoiwqueoiwqueoiwq",
"url": "http:\/\/192.168.63.175:3000\/users\/3.json"
}
```

Here, we have the same `object` as above example. So the model class will be the same, but like above example we dont have an array of these objects - just one single object and hence we dont need to parse it as a list.

So make the following changes for an `object response`

```
public interface ContactsInterface {
    @GET("/users.json")
    Call<Contacts> getContacts();
    }
```

Then make the `retrofit2` call like the following

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("baseurl_here")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    ContactsInterface request = retrofit.create(ContactsInterface.class);
    Call<Contacts> call = request.getContacts();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Contacts>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Contacts> call, Response<Contacts> response) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response.body().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Contacts> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Error",t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

`response.body()` will give you the object

You may also check a common error while parsing json object response :[*"expected begin_array but was begin_object"*](https://www.freshbytelabs.com/2018/05/how-to-fix-expected-beginarray-but-was.html)

**`Case 3 : Parsing a json array inside json object`**

This case applies to those `json responses` which are of the form **`{"array_name":[{...} ,{...}]}`**

E.g.

```
    {
    "contacts": 
         [
            {
             "id": 3,
             "username": "jezer",
             "regid": "oiqwueoiwqueoiwqueoiwq",
             "url": "http:\/\/192.168.63.175:3000\/users\/3.json"
            }
         ]
    }
```

You will need two model classes here since we have two objects(one outside and one inside the array).Generate it like below

**`ContactWrapper`**

```
public class ContactWrapper {

@SerializedName("contacts")
@Expose
private List<Contacts> contacts = null;

public List<Contacts> getContacts() {
return contacts;
}

public void setContacts(List<Contacts> contacts) {
this.contacts = contacts;
}

}
```

You can use **`Contacts.java`** generated above for the list objects(generated for case 1)

So make the following changes for an `object response`

```
public interface ContactsInterface {
    @GET("/users.json")
    Call<ContactWrapper> getContacts();
    }
```

Then make the `retrofit2` call like the following

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("baseurl_here")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    ContactsInterface request = retrofit.create(ContactsInterface.class);
    Call<ContactWrapper> call = request.getContacts();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ContactWrapper>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ContactWrapper> call, Response<ContactWrapper> response) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response.body().getContacts().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ContactWrapper> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Error",t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

Here, the difference from case 1 is that we should use `response.body().getContacts()` instead of `response.body()` to get the list of objects

Some references for above cases :

case 1 : [Parsing a json array response](https://www.freshbytelabs.com/2018/12/parse-json-array-in-android-with-free.html),
case 2 : [Parsing a json object response](https://www.freshbytelabs.com/2018/12/parse-json-object-in-android-with-free.html),
mixed : [Parsing json array inside another json object](https://www.freshbytelabs.com/2018/12/parse-json-array-inside-json-object-in.html)

Comment: hai i am trying to request getting data in 3rd format but i am continuously getting the  same error  can you please help me

Comment: please provide more info about your code, also make sure your array name spelling  in the model  class matches exactly with that of response

Answer (score 8):

in your interface
replace

```
@GET("/users.json")
void contacts(Callback<Contacts> cb);
```

By this code

```
@GET("/users.json")
void contacts(Callback<List<Contacts>> cb);
```

Comment: this appears to be the same answer minus the description that was posted by Jake Wharton.

Comment: It's true, I had the same error and before modifying the pojo I decided to create an arrayList and get the same result

Answer (score 1):

Convert it into a list.

Below is the example:

```
BenchmarksListModel_v1[] benchmarksListModel = res.getBody().as(BenchmarksListModel_v1[].class);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Source Code Working**

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzBKpZ4nzNzUVFRnVVkzc0JabUU

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("inbox.json")
    Call<List<Message>> getInbox();
}

 call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Message>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Message>> call, Response<List<Message>> response) {

        YourpojoClass.addAll(response.body());

                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Message>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch json: " + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: i have tried like this but i am getting response.body() as [ ] empty....no data in it please help me

Answer (score 0):

Using **MPV**, in your Deserializer, put this

```
JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
obj.add("data", json);

JsonArray data  = obj.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("data");
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation as to why this solves the problem

Comment: If the server response has a JSON format like this `{[..]}`, then retrofit can't iterate correctly, a prefix must be placed on the JSON, as Jake Wharton suggests. the final JSON would be like this `{"data":[..]}` and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

The stack here is Kotlin, Retrofit2, RxJava and we're migrating to that off regular `Call` methods.

The service that I had created was throwing `com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException` and `java.lang.IllegalStateException` with message:

```
Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column2
```

But all the answers I could find said that this was caused by not having an **array** type in the service, which I already did.  My Kotlin service looked like this:

```
// Data class. Retrofit2 & Gson can deserialize this. No extra code needed. 
data class InventoryData(
    val productCode: String,
    val stockDate: String,
    val availCount: Int,
    val totalAvailCount: Int,
    val inventorySold: Int,
    val closed: Boolean
    )

// BROKEN SERVICE. Throws com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException
// Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column2
interface InventoryService {

    @GET("getInventoryData/{storeId}")
    fun getInventoryData(@Path("storeId") storeId: String,
                         @Query("startDate") startDate: String,
                         @Query("endDate") endDate: String) :
            Result<Single<List<InventoryData>>>
}
```

The problem was the `Result` in there, which I had put in when I was using an earlier `Call` based solution.

Removing it fixed the problem.  I also had to change the signature of the two error handling methods at my call-site for the service:

```
/// WORKING SERVICE
interface InventoryService {

    @GET("getInventoryData/{storeId}")
    fun getInventoryData(@Path("storeId") storeId: String,
                         @Query("startDate") startDate: String,
                         @Query("endDate") endDate: String) :
            Single<List<InventoryData>>
}
```

And the call-site fragment code that uses the service:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    viewModel.disposables
            .add(viewModel.ratsService.getInventoryData(it, fromDate, toDate)
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .subscribe(this::successResult, this::failureResult))
    }
}

private fun failureResult(error: Throwable) {
    when (error) {
        is HttpException -> { if (error.code() == 401) {
                            textField.text = "Log in required!" } }
        else -> textField.text = "Error: $error."
    }
}

/// Had to change to this from previous broken 
/// one that took `Result<List<InventoryData>>`
private fun successResult(result: List<InventoryData>) {
    textField.text = result.toString()
}
```

Note that the above code has been changed a little.  In particular I used a Retrofit2 `ConverterFactory` to allow the dates to be passed in as OffsetDateTime objects instead of strings.