# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path from Retrofit

Tags: android, listview, retrofit, android-viewholder

I want to receive data from retrofit, and set it in `ListView`, but I have an exception

> retrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was
>   BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

what must I do?

#### Retrofit:

```
public class Retrofit {

    private static final String ENDPOINT = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place";
    private static ApiInterface apiInterface;

    interface ApiInterface {
        @GET("/nearbysearch/json?location=49.9944422,36.2368201&radius=500&types=food&key=AIzaSyDQZoJKznf0uRkvJFqLYbZ7-1GeGudjmv0")
        void getBars(Callback<List<Bars>> callback);    
    }

    static {
        init();
    }

    private static void init() {
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(ENDPOINT)
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .build();
        apiInterface = restAdapter.create(ApiInterface.class);
    }

    public static void getBars(Callback<List<Bars>> callback) {
        apiInterface.getBars(callback);
    }
}
```

#### Class:

```
public class Bars implements Serializable {

    String name;
    String vicinity;

    public Bars(String name, String vicinity) {
        this.name = name;
        this.vicinity = vicinity;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getVicinity() {
        return vicinity;
    }

    public void setVicinity(String vicinity) {
        this.vicinity = vicinity;
    }
}
```

#### Retrofit in Activity:

```
Retrofit.getBars(new Callback<List<Bars>>() {
    @Override
    public void success(List<Bars> bars, Response response) {

        listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, bars));
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("Retrofit error", error.toString());

    }
});
```

#### Adapter:

```
class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Bars> {

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Bars> objects) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        View rowView = convertView;
        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textNameOfBar = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.name_id);
            holder.textVicinity = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.vicinity_id);

            rowView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }

        Bars bars = getItem(position);
        holder.textNameOfBar.setText(bars.getName());
        holder.textVicinity.setText(bars.getVicinity());


        return rowView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {

        public TextView textNameOfBar;
        public TextView textVicinity;
    }
}
```

Data looks like:

```
D/Retrofit: ogle.com/maps/contrib/111140660648735044302/photos\"\u003eОтель Гостиный Двор\u003c/a\u003e"
],
"photo_reference": "CmRdAAAA0qow_LjH6-RujURITuXtpvNeQpJ0xaIy7dL80VRhLjp-OMIXJYsIGj0XlkB6SRiORlmW_RxqbkGGaM2yyB6bOkz3RBSwzVmgtP3kLeN1JAwxpW62LFn2hvdc_921_JNZEhDfmW37jl6FYQ4mLtYZDwA0GhTFUWldj0Bbi1EdkzBrjcu0xVeqgA",
"width": 627
}
],
"place_id": "ChIJiZnTsuWgJ0ERVUB0bbViq7k",
"reference": "CnRmAAAAEF4DAZnJz_OxXVua7ChBhxS7CQFgMNlkA1c-8MnzeqVoIWRwyMTQOr7bMcjI16jRmFs5uYc6_Zb-9YTjjamXgYzO6ymZbrmR8tmA0alkr8CcmI37lUrKJvAUYy5l2-O80EVq314RWp7Set0bfcLzwRIQE1WYSj1Vasoa4eZ0kAW49hoU4JT9ABn_MCbF_s8PTDVpE86HfEk",
"scope": "GOOGLE",
"types": ["restaurant", "food", "lodging", "point_of_interest", "establishment"],
"vicinity": "Rimarskaya Str.28, Kharkiv"
}, {
    "geometry": {
        "location": {
            "lat": 49.994499,
            "lng": 36.237983
        }
    },
    "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/lodging-71.png",
    "id": "6a63d528bbd4d7461fe1062f3e10f2575d51574f",
    "name": "Reikartz Kharkiv",
    "opening_hours": {
        "open_now": true,
        "weekday_text": []
    },
    "photos": [{
        "height": 768,
        "html_attributions": [
            "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/104215460438823286508/photos\"\u003eReikartz Харьков\u003c/a\u003e"
        ],
        "photo_reference": "CmRdAAAA8lNiz4Z2yK0AD20LLblcrDoWvGVjrp3datMDcq2Sj9V7ktRA6pajcQ1v_TlwhHVNrm-73MwUGZqnlVgQLS3EzNwfzHhs2irIMzO2oqg75dVBFpCYGP57PeuhWDJ-W53UEhCF71N-dozQfnzsaLeYnBUjGhQYbbIHm_9RjSyB3dKT9Nazlch8BQ",
        "width": 1024
    }],
    "place_id": "ChIJaSzvVO6gJ0ERtIpreEKDltw",
    "rating": 4.6,
    "reference": "CnRkAAAA1U-Hp0Nep02UFPtGcfn_W_qTYdAzPjv5teMOr2tNeNdaGHjfHX1riTR8JMG3rNyIXJTpXnjI5ZtfivNCf94pF-IzX39guAmTRRvLkXGBOS4z1Ty9_sgOK5DmZx6UKNeMS_SfZFA0j5OfeGtDlXI9JhIQ4MEkLnOpvIzNhfSOfgYHjRoUAeoSxp0NqOlmvnFsS8HGaUCdBsk",
    "scope": "GOOGLE",
    "types": ["restaurant", "food", "lodging", "point_of_interest", "establishment"],
    "vicinity": "Sadova Street, 4, Kharkiv"
}, {
    "geometry": {
        "location": {
            "lat": 49.9904245,
            "lng": 36.2344184
        }
    },
    "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
    "id": "1d18eefa6be027ae1a18c9ed421917dfab8fbe8c",
    "name": "МИЛЕНА, РЕСТОРАН",
    "place_id": "ChIJI34e5fOgJ0ER6vn5PcHDGeA",
    "reference": "CoQBcgAAAENtH6QLvT7_n8LlEsWSpMgQ562g5BDsAKdN_P98RRAs-WEsecVZ255_5TPWQTFeuZwuq8s7q8-VukDDnAYai3PHlu8Uy2r9H7sbIxkN5HxYs5KFFs1WAWESN8GtaaCTJzz6gkHeoYUyP0jb5wgxnPKWMu6lWLVUO3m2BZueQ3vOEhAwht5-huQPLsVSnpNROXVRGhSjF6AX4cChwhvKweczKsDO7kZBfg",
    "scope": "GOOGLE",
    "types": ["restaurant", "food", "point_of_interest", "establishment"],
    "vicinity": "Korolenka Lane, 4, Kharkiv"
}, {
    "geometry": {
        "location": {
            "lat": 49.99132549999999,
            "lng": 36.2320451
        }
    },
    "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/cafe-71.png",
    "id": "a7bab463a9623445a7f9e82ef18982abfe131d7c",
    "name": "Kofeynya F.R.I.E.N.D.S",
    "photos": [{
                "height": 2448,
                "html_attributions": [
                    "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/112321527648150256042/photos\"\u003eВладимир опенченко\u003c/a\u003e"
                ],
                "photo_reference": "CmRdAAAA6BLiXNDxmlvAo7wbBg_NakRA_mIlLoBUNhGMQ3ArVQGC6Li5m17-cjQzpQmdgSli8QWFVAu-UVk-jRyCkacQ7SHiKgHhvkwZDXWArutJChOYIs5uZabItJ-mHIgxuahYEhBsPO1M294IfxJ8b_19aH8MGhSC37RX
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154917/retrofit-expected-begin-object-but-was-begin-array

Comment: please, next time check older questions first before posting because your question might have been answered.

Answer (score 0):

> This error came when response is in JSONObject and you made JSONArray POJO.I solved my problem like this.
>   Make JSONObject POJO like below:

```
public class GetEventResult {

@SerializedName("event")
@Expose
private Event event;

public Event getEvent() {
    return event;
}

public void setEvent(Event event) {
    this.event = event;
}
}
```

> Instead of this:

```
public class OneRegistryBeanResult {

@SerializedName("event")
@Expose
private List<Event> event = new ArrayList<Event>();

public List<Event> getEvent() {
    return event;
}

public void setEvent(List<Event> event) {
    this.event = event;
}
}
```