# How to parse JSON response Array of object, where array is without key name

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, jsonparser

I am trying to parse json result without array name. Here is my json response:

```
[
    {
        "Id": 2293,
        "Name": "Dr.",
        "Active": true
    },
    {
        "Id": 2305,
        "Name": "Mr.",
        "Active": true
    },
    {
        "Id": 2315,
        "Name": "Mrs.",
        "Active": true
    }
]
```

How to parse this using `com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0` library?

Comment: use a List of your Model class as `Retrofit` response.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50355221/8009433

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create One Class Like,

```
class Test {

     public List<TestValue> testValues;
}
```

Then call API,

```
Call<List<Test>> getTestData(@Field("xyz") String field1);


   Call <List<Test>> call = service.getTestData("val");

   call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Test>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<Test>> call, Response<List<Test>> 
                              response) {

        List<Test> rs = response.body();

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<Test>> call, Throwable t) {

    }
});
```

User Your Model class, this is only for example purpose.

Answer (score 0):

**Normally you can parse as**

```
String response = "[{"Id": 2293,"Name": "Dr.","Active": true},{"Id": 2305,"Name": "Mr.","Active": true},{"Id": 2315,"Name": "Mrs.","Active": true}]";
    try {
        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(response);
        for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
            String id = jo.getString("Id");
            String name = jo.getString("Name");
            String active = jo.getString("Active");
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If you want to parse it using `Model Class` then your `Model Class` will be for `Retrofit`

```
 class Response
{

    @SerializedName("Id")
    @Expose
    private String id;

    @SerializedName("Name")
    @Expose
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("Active")
    @Expose
    private String active;

}
```

and define Callback for retrofit like that

```
Call<List<Meeting>> getMeetings(@Field String data );
```

Hope this will help