# how to access jsonarray using retrofit

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

how to access `districtID(key)` value and `name(key)` value using `retrofit` ?

**this is json file...**

```
{
    "error": false,
    "message": "District successfully fetched.",
    "districts": [
        {
            "districtID": "DIS260920181",
            "name": "Raipur"
        },
        {
            "districtID": "DIS260920182",
            "name": "Bilaspur"
        },
        {
            "districtID": "DIS011020186",
            "name": "korba"
        },
        {
            "districtID": "DIS011020187",
            "name": "jagdalpur"
        },
        {
            "districtID": "DIS021020188",
            "name": "surguja"
        },
        {
            "districtID": "DIS021020189",
            "name": "Mungeli"
        }
    ]
}
```

Please help :(

Comment: retrofit has nothing to do with JSON. It only makes network calls

Comment: ok  Vladyslav Matviienko, but how to access api data ??

Comment: You can make model class and use that model class as response and from that response you can get that variable

Comment: show how you load it first

Comment: i'm facing problem -  **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $ **

Comment: @SurjeetNandi check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50355221/8009433

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert JSON Array into POJO classes and then call api using retrofit network call.

Comment: after this i'm facing problem - **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $**

Answer (score 0):

Use this [link](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

copy your json and it gives you two model class you should put the parent class which contains error , message and districts as your output in your request. something like this

```
@GET("your_url")
Call<ModelExample> nameOfMethod();
```

And then you have list of districts. you can access to the items and districtID and name
I hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
      for onResponse:
   --------------------------
        Call<ModalClass> daoCall = api.getconnectdata();
          modelclass.enqueue(new Callback<ModalClass>() {
           @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ModalClass> call, Response<ModalClass> 
            response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    modelclass= response.body();
             List<Districts>  list = modelclass.getAddData().getData();
             adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),list);
               listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }
```

Comment: i m facing problem - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: check it ur response .i think ur response not correct way