# How to solve JSON retrofit error with Deferred Response

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mvvm, retrofit2

I followed with tutorial : https://android.jlelse.eu/android-networking-in-2019-retrofit-with-kotlins-coroutines-aefe82c4d777

I need to recover data in `JSON` format, I get the following error message :

```
com.squareup.moshi.JsonDataException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at path $*
```

I looked at this answer but I don't know how to adapt it to my code : [Retrofit Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154917/retrofit-expected-begin-object-but-was-begin-array)

**This is my interface**

```
interface LocationService {
    @GET("locations?countryid=fr")
    fun getLocationList() : Deferred<Response<LocationResponse>>
}
```

**LocationResponse**

```
data class LocationResponse (val results : List<Location>)
```

**Location Model**

```
data class Location (
    @field:Json(name = "id") val id : String,
    @field:Json(name = "category") val category : String,
    @field:Json(name = "label") val label : String,
    @field:Json(name = "value") val value : String
)
```

**The JSON is like this**

```
[
  {
    "id":"city_39522",
    "category":"Villes",
    "label":"Parisot (81310)",
    "value":null
 },
 {
   "id":"city_36661",
   "category":"Villes",
   "label":"Paris 9ème (75009)",
   "value":null
 },
 {
   "id":"city_39743",
   "category":"Villes",
   "label":"Parisot (82160)",
   "value":null
 }
]
```

I'm already getting a list, I don't see how to correct the error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You have to update your interface as:**

```
interface LocationService {
    @GET("locations?countryid=fr")
    fun getLocationList() : Deferred<Response<List<Location>>>
}
```

Also you don't need **`LocationResponse`** class and remove the below code:

```
data class LocationResponse (val results : List<Location>)
```

**You are expecting the response and parsing it like this:**

```
{
  "results": [
    { .. }
  ]
}
```

**But Actual response is like this:**

```
 [
    { .. }
  ]
```

The error explains that you are expecting object at the root but actual json data is array, so you have to change it to array.

Comment: @Asue glad to hear that!

Answer (score 1):

In your API interface you're defining **getLocationList()** method to return a LocationResponse object whereas the API actually returns a list of objects, so to fix this define the method as follows..

```
interface LocationService {
    @GET("locations?countryid=fr")
    fun getLocationList() : Deferred<Response<List<Location>>>
}
```