# Retrofit 2 didn't get any response in list

Tags: android, retrofit2

Here is my JSON look like

[image: JSON Image]

When I tried to access the son using list. I check that `response.isSuccessful()` I am getting true in response but can not see data in model classes.

Here is my **MainActivity**

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        ApiInterface apiInterface = APIClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

        Call<List<Example>> call = apiInterface.getAdditionalProperties(APIClient.TOKEN,APIClient.SECRET,"1s","now");

      call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Example>>() {
          @Override
          public void onResponse(Call<List<Example>> call, Response<List<Example>> response) {

              if (response.isSuccessful())
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(response.body().toString()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              List<Example> exampleList = response.body();

              for (int i = 0; i < exampleList.size(); i++) {
                  System.out.println(exampleList.get(i).getAccount());
              }
          }

          @Override
          public void onFailure(Call<List<Example>> call, Throwable t) {
              Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
          }
      });
    }
```

**APIClient.java**

```
public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
```

Here is my interface

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("data?")
    Call<List<Example>> getAdditionalProperties(@Query("mc_token") String token, @Query("mc_secret") String secret, @Query("utc_start") String startTime, @Query("utc_end") String endTime);

}
```

You can see my models look like this

[image: Model Image]

**Example**

```
public class Example {

    private String account;
    private String type;
    private String topic;
    private String platform;
    private double utcTimeApiReceived;
    private String key;
    private String device;
    private Data data;
    private String id;
    private double utcTime;
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    public String getAccount() {
        return account;
    }

    public void setAccount(String account) {
        this.account = account;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getTopic() {
        return topic;
    }

    public void setTopic(String topic) {
        this.topic = topic;
    }

    public String getPlatform() {
        return platform;
    }

    public void setPlatform(String platform) {
        this.platform = platform;
    }

    public double getUtcTimeApiReceived() {
        return utcTimeApiReceived;
    }

    public void setUtcTimeApiReceived(double utcTimeApiReceived) {
        this.utcTimeApiReceived = utcTimeApiReceived;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getDevice() {
        return device;
    }

    public void setDevice(String device) {
        this.device = device;
    }

    public Data getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Data data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public double getUtcTime() {
        return utcTime;
    }

    public void setUtcTime(double utcTime) {
        this.utcTime = utcTime;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

}
```

I checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154917/retrofit-expected-begin-object-but-was-begin-array) and try It but it didn't help

If you would like to see my model code feel free.

Thank You

Comment: Why are you using `?` at path section?
Try with `data`

Comment: Please attach code of your `APIClient.getClient()` method

Comment: after removing? it showing same output