# Android onResponse method is never called Retrofit2

Tags: android

first of all I know that this question has already been asked many times. But I cannot find a solution to the problem. From the log I can see that the web service correctly returns the JSON to me. But for some reason it never enters the onResponse method. I would be very grateful if someone could give me a hint on this matter.

```
    package com.example.hms_android_application;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.hms_android_application.Retrofit.Account;
import com.example.hms_android_application.Retrofit.INodeJS;
import com.example.hms_android_application.Retrofit.RetrofitClient;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView edt_firstq,
            edt_midq,
            edt_famq,
            edt_phoneq,
            edt_adressq,
            edt_usernameq,
            edt_passwordq,     edt_egnq,edt_bloodq,edt_genderq;
    Button btn_regs;
    private String u_username;
    private Account account;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        edt_usernameq =  findViewById(R.id.textView13);
        edt_passwordq =  findViewById(R.id.textView14);

        edt_adressq =  findViewById(R.id.textView15);
        edt_egnq = findViewById(R.id.textView16);

        edt_famq =  findViewById(R.id.textView17);
        edt_firstq =  findViewById(R.id.textView18);

        edt_phoneq =  findViewById(R.id.textView19);
        edt_midq =  findViewById(R.id.textView20);

        edt_bloodq =  findViewById(R.id.textView21);
        edt_genderq =  findViewById(R.id.textView22);


        btn_regs = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
        loadData();
    }

    private void loadData(){

            Intent intent = getIntent();
            u_username = intent.getStringExtra("u_username");
            INodeJS accountservice = RetrofitClient.getInstance().create(INodeJS.class);
            accountservice.find(u_username).enqueue(new Callback<Account>() {

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Account> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.createfield), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Account> call, Response<Account> response) {
                    try {
                        if(response.isSuccessful()){
                            account =  response.body();
                            edt_firstq.setText(account.getpFirstName());
                            edt_usernameq.setText(account.getuUsername());
                            edt_adressq.setText(account.getpAddress());
                            edt_egnq.setText(account.getpEgn());
                            edt_famq.setText(account.getpFamilyName());
                            edt_phoneq.setText(account.getpPhone());
                            edt_midq.setText(account.getpMidName());
                            edt_bloodq.setText(account.getpBloodGroup());
                            edt_genderq.setText(account.getpGender());
                            edt_passwordq.setText(account.getuUsername());

                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.app_name), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            });
    }

}
```

RetrofitClient

```
    public class RetrofitClient {
    private  static Retrofit instance = null;
    public  static Retrofit getInstance(){
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();
            instance = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("http://192.168.100.103:3000/")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(client)
                    .build();
        return instance;

    }
}
```

Interface

```
public interface INodeJS {

    @POST("login/")
    Call<Boolean> login(@Body Account account);

    @POST("register/")
Call<Boolean> create(@Body Account account);

    @GET("user/{u_username}")
    Call<Account> find(@Path("u_username") String u_username);
}
```

Account

```
    public class Account implements Serializable {
    @SerializedName("p_first_name")
    @Expose
    private String pFirstName;
    @SerializedName("p_mid_name")
    @Expose
    private String pMidName;
    @SerializedName("p_family_name")
    @Expose
    private String pFamilyName;
    @SerializedName("p_egn")
    @Expose
    private String pEgn;
    @SerializedName("p_gender")
    @Expose
    private String pGender;
    @SerializedName("p_phone")
    @Expose
    private String pPhone;
    @SerializedName("p_address")
    @Expose
    private String pAddress;
    @SerializedName("p_blood_group")
    @Expose
    private String pBloodGroup;
    @SerializedName("u_password")
    @Expose
    private String uPassword;
    @SerializedName("u_username")
    @Expose
    private String uUsername;

    public String getpFirstName() {
        return pFirstName;
    }

    public void setpFirstName(String pFirstName) {
        this.pFirstName = pFirstName;
    }

    public String getpMidName() {
        return pMidName;
    }

    public void setpMidName(String pMidName) {
        this.pMidName = pMidName;
    }

    public String getpFamilyName() {
        return pFamilyName;
    }

    public void setpFamilyName(String pFamilyName) {
        this.pFamilyName = pFamilyName;
    }

    public String getpEgn() {
        return pEgn;
    }

    public void setpEgn(String pEgn) {
        this.pEgn = pEgn;
    }

    public String getpGender() {
        return pGender;
    }

    public void setpGender(String pGender) {
        this.pGender = pGender;
    }

    public String getpPhone() {
        return pPhone;
    }

    public void setpPhone(String pPhone) {
        this.pPhone = pPhone;
    }

    public String getpAddress() {
        return pAddress;
    }

    public void setpAddress(String pAddress) {
        this.pAddress = pAddress;
    }

    public String getpBloodGroup() {
        return pBloodGroup;
    }

    public void setpBloodGroup(String pBloodGroup) {
        this.pBloodGroup = pBloodGroup;
    }

    public String getuPassword() {
        return uPassword;
    }

    public void setuPassword(String uPassword) {
        this.uPassword = uPassword;
    }

    public String getuUsername() {
        return uUsername;
    }

    public void setuUsername(String uUsername) {
        this.uUsername = uUsername;
    }
}
```

Log out

```
 I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: --> GET http://192.168.100.103:3000/user/mariq12
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: --> END GET
I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=78KB, data=93KB
I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=76KB, data=69KB
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- 200 OK http://192.168.100.103:3000/user/mariq12 (162ms)
    X-Powered-By: Express
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    Content-Length: 290
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: ETag: W/"122-zx+JBLEne+i9Ys0+0Y2w7hRX3RM"
    Date: Thu, 17 Dec 2020 17:04:52 GMT
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Connection: keep-alive
    Keep-Alive: timeout=5
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: [{"p_first_name":"Мария","p_mid_name":"Стоянова","p_family_name":"Петрова","p_egn":"8502018520","p_gender":"Жена","p_phone":"0873025145","p_address":"\"ул.Тодор Петров 22\" Варна","p_blood_group":"A+","u_password":"mariq12","u_username":"mariq12"}]
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- END HTTP (290-byte body)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xd6f2aba0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe587bd30)
I/chatty: uid=10079(com.example.hms_android_application) RenderThread identical 1 line
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xd6f2aba0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe587bd30)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xd6f2aba0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe587bd30)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xd6f2aba0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe587bd30)
```

I tried to see what a mistake it was.

```
public void onFailure(Call<Account> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
```

The mistake he makes is

```
 com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, try to log your onResponse() method. So in your onResponse method you should add this line

```
Log.d("ResponseTAG",  "onResponse() called: " + response.code());
```

Than try to find this Log in your logcat. Run your code, go to logcat, filter your TAG there.

Your logcat should contain this filters: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3fyi.png)

If u find in log cat this text:
*onResponse() called: RESPONSE_CODE*
That means your onResponse() is called, but some exception occures. And because you catch **all exceptions...**

```
                    try {
                        
                    catch (Exception e){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
```

Your code in try block not working. So try to catch other Exception class, .

Comment: When I do that, nothing comes out. It probably onResponse() doesn't work, but how can I run it.

Comment: You've got this code, which creates toast when exception has been caught
catch (Exception e){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

so is this toast visible or not?

Comment: Yes, all the same, this feature does not exist, but goes straight to onFailure. There I put t.printStackTrace (); and prints com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

Answer (score 0):

You've got JsonSyntaxException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY

That means: your JSON response containes JSONArray, not JSONObject.
In your case you've got array of Account models. Not specific user, but list of users. So u can create ArrayList f.e.

```
private List<Account> photoArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

and load your Account class models there
private void loadData(){

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    u_username = intent.getStringExtra("u_username");
    INodeJS accountservice = RetrofitClient.getInstance().create(INodeJS.class);
    accountservice.find(u_username).enqueue(new Callback<List<Account>>() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Account>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.createfield), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Account>> call, Response<Account> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                yourArrayList.addAll(response.body);
            }
            

        }
    });
}
```

if it doesn't work again, try to change Interface method

```
@GET("user/{u_username}")
    Call<List<Account>> find(@Path("u_username") String u_username);
```

And finally u can read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50355221/9972209)

Comment: Which error now? What is your logs? Your exception tells that you receive BEGIN_ARRAY, not BEGIN_OBJECT. So your find interface method should return <List<Account>>, not single object of Account class. And when you enqueue, you should also pass Callback<List<Account>> as a parameter